# How To Remove CSRFTOKEN From The Cookie?

Tags: jmeter, postman, postman-collection-runner

[image][image]In Postman Or Jmeter, I want to call a POST API for 100 users in my collection, but after each user login, csrftoken is added to the cookie with the session, but the POST API fails when the cookie contains a csrftoken.
so how to delete the csrftoken from the cookie while maintaining the session ?

Comment: Can you post the image of your postman headers tab

Answer (score 0):

Use this as test-script in the postman request. (Note that you have to whitelist your domain in the cookie manager window if you run the collection from postman)

```
const cookieJar = pm.cookies.jar()
cookieJar.unset("domain.com", "csrftoken", function(error){
})
```

[Refer documentation for more details](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/cookies/#delete-a-cookie)

Comment: can you provide the error you are getting? or some screenshots of your postman on how you are using the script ?

Comment: I attached some screenshots

Comment: have you whitelisted your domain ? can you log the error in from the callback function to see if there is an error ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to **remove** this CSRF token cookie, you need to **send correct one**.

Not knowing the details of your application it is hard to say what exactly needs to be done, i.e. where the token comes from. If it is being sent by your application in the [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header in JMeter it will be enough to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

If it comes in the different header or in the response body - you will need to extract it from the previous response using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and manually add the needed cookie in the HTTP Cookie Manager.

More information: [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites/)